# Find the probability of this event

Tags: probability, statistics

Two teams play a best-of -seven series, in which the series ends as soon as one team wins four games. The first two games are to be played on A's field , the next three games on B's field, and the last two on A's field. The probability that A wins a game is $0.7$ at home and $0.5$ away. Assume that the games are independent. Find the probability, that the series does not go to $6$ games.
My Answer is

$$2\cdot 0.7\cdot 0.7\cdot 0.5\cdot 0.5\cdot 0.5\\+2\cdot 0.7\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.5\cdot 0.5\cdot 0.5\\+2\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.5\cdot 0.5\cdot 0.5\\+2\cdot 0.7\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.5\cdot 0.5\cdot 0.5\\=0.25$$
But the correct answer is $0.397$.
How to get the correct answer?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you count for the 2 cases where A or B sweeps the series and wins in 4 games?

Comment: When asking this question, it would make it easier on the reader if you explain your logic for each term, or at least for the first one.  Something like "the chance that A wins two at home and two on the road is ___ given that they have to win the last one for the series to end in five games.

Answer (score 1):

We want the probability that the series lasts $4$ or $5$ games.

Team A sweeps in $4$ with probability $(0.7)^2(0.5)^2$, and Team B sweeps with probability $(0.3)^2(0.5)^2$. The probability of a sweep is $0.145$.

The $5$ game analysis is lengthier. Let's first deal with Team A winning in $5$. Team A has to win the fifth game (probability $0.5$, and $3$ of the first $4$. So it has to either (i) win its $2$ home games, and $1$ of the $2$ away games or (ii)
it has to win $1$ home game, and $2$ away games.

Event (i) has probability $(0.7)^2(2)(0.5)^2$. Event (ii) has probability $(2)(0.7)(0.3)(0.5)^2$, for a total of $(0.5)((0.7)^2(2)(0.5)^2+(2)(0.7)(0.3)(0.5)^2)$. This is $0.175$.

A similar calculation for B winning in $5$ gives $(0.5)((0.3)^2(2)(0.5)^2+(2)(0.7)(0.3)(0.5)^2)$. This is $0.075$.

Add up. We get $0.395$.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: We can avoid some of the details for the second case (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

A solution with a bit less computation:

Note that no matter who wins the first two games, there are exactly $2$ combinations of the three away results that make the series end on the fifth game (if the same team wins the first two games, the $2$ choices for the third game determine the rest; if different teams win the first two games, the $2$ choices for the fifth game determine the rest). So we don't need the winning probabilities in the first two games to find that the series ends on the fifth game with probability $2\cdot0.5^3=0.25$.

As determined by André Nicolas, the series ends on the fourth game with probability $0.7^2\cdot0.5^2+0.3^2\cdot0.5^2=0.145$, so the total probability for ending before the sixth game is $0.25+0.145=0.395$.